Why is Raydium swap not working on ubuntu server but its perfectly working on my windows pc and Ubuntu WSL?
I am trying to run this project from github:https://github.com/precious-void/raydium-swap, this is basic raydium swap example its working perfectly in local windows and WSL but its not running on my ubuntu server always getting this error, always showing KILLED:


Your server may have run out of memory, causing the OOM killer to kill your program. Be sure that there's enough RAM on your server!
